# Link float to right not aligned with background box in small screens

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a red box with a link float all the way to the right of a paragraph text.

HTML

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="content">
      <p class="paragraph">long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text!!!<a class="link" target="_blank" href="https://abcde.com/">LINK</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.card {
   display: block;
}

.content {

}

.paragraph {
   background: red;
   padding: 1rem;
   border-radius: 0.5rem;
   line-height: 20px;
   font-size: 1rem;
}

.link {
   float: right;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 500;
}
```

It works just fine in normal in large screens:
[image]

But when I test in small screens, the `LINK` goes outside the red box and not aligned:
[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: you may want to use a flexbox for this

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox approach.

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="content" style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:end">
      <p class="paragraph">long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text!!!</p>
      <a class="link" target="_blank" href="https://abcde.com/">LINK</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This puts the LINK outside of the red box.

Comment: you just have to give the background to the `content`, not to the `p`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use flexbox
2. Or "position: absolute" for link (and position:relative for container)

Comment: flexbox for the card div? Do you have an example?